# What pressure does liquid nitrous oxide need at −45 °C?

Tags: physical-chemistry, phase, temperature, pressure, liquids

What pressure does liquid nitrous oxide need at −45 °C to remain liquid? How can I calculate its pressure required for other temperatures?

Comment: Rather read from phase diagram then calculate, unless you find curve fitting equation.

Comment: @Mithoron Would you point me to a phase diagram to read this from? I could really not find a decent one.

Comment: I also found a bad one...

Comment: «Nitrous oxide: Saturation properties and the phase diagram», Ferreira, Lobo, The Journal of Chemical Thermodynamics, 41, 2009, 1394-1399, [doi 10.1016/j.jct.2009.06.017](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jct.2009.06.017), seems to cover the range you need here.

Comment: If such a diagram was not available, or for other compound, one could use  the knowledge of the boiling point, the evaporation molar enthalpy (or its approximation by the empirical rule ( forgot the rule name ) saying evaporation molar entropy change is 90 J/K/mol and the [Clausius-Clapeyron equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausius%E2%80%93Clapeyron_relation).) Then it is possible to compute the approximation of the curve p_vap  = f(T)

Answer (score 3):

Using *NIST Reference Fluid Thermodynamic and Transport Properties Database (REFPROP)* – NIST Standard Reference Database 23, Version 9, I found the saturation point of nitrous oxide at equilibrium for a temperature of $T=-45.000\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$ at a pressure of $p=783110\ \mathrm{Pa}=7.8311\ \mathrm{bar}$;
for $T=-78.000\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$, it is $p=182290\ \mathrm{Pa}=1.8229\ \mathrm{bar}$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was about to ask if there may be a (freely accessible) online database/calculator where one could get this info and I just found this REFPROP version 10 is selling for $325 here: https://www.nist.gov/srd/refprop I guess you have purchased that, right? Would you mind looking up one more value - pressure for -78°C? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like there is an alternative to REFPROP - it is called CoolProp. Not very user friendly though. Website: http://www.coolprop.org/